# determinantal hypersurface singular in codimension 1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I know that the general linear symmetric determinantal hypersurface is singular in codimension 2.

**Questions.**

(1) What can we say about linear symmetric determinantal hypersurfaces singular in codimension 1?

(2) Is there a property that characterize them?

(3) Can these be irreducible?

Comment: For instance $\det\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & y & x \\ y & x & 0 \\ x & 0 & z \end{smallmatrix}\right) = 0$ is a cuspidal cubic.

Comment: For the curves the situation is different, by if I cut the secant variety of the Veronese surface with a subspace of dimension 3, then the hypersurface obtained is singular in codimension 1 if and only if it is singular.

Comment: A cone over a cuspidal cubic is determinantal (by the same matrix), so curves are not very special.

Comment: I wasn't precise enough. I was thinking of determinantal symmetric hypersurfaces such that the corank 2 matrices form a subvariety of codimension 1.